# is there a way in ipython to always run an import on startup? like 'from __future__ import division'?

Tags: python, ipython

The reason is that I sometimes use the shell/interpreter as a calculator and pretty much *always* want true division, and i'm tired of always typing it in!

Comment: people run python 3 in production?!  hahahah jk jk  -->  http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-dev/129499/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open `~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` and search for `c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines`. I'm using IPython 1.2, and it's right at the top of the file. Set it like so:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ["from __future__ import division", "import something", "another statement"]
```

with each string being a line of Python code you want executed when IPython starts. Save the file, restart IPython, and you should be all set.

If this file does not exist, create a profile by running

```sh
ipython profile create
```

at the command line and it will be automatically generated for you.

Comment: You can also use [startup files](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/interactive/tutorial.html#startup-files) for regular imports, though they won't work for `__future__` imports.